# Problems with loops in Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, arrays

Hey I have an array with numbers in it.

Now I want to divide the value at 17th position of the array by the value at the first position of the array, then the 18th by the second, and so on. The results should build a new array.

Then I want to scan all values of the new array and if two or more successive values are bigger than 1.2, I want to add the result of dividing the first by the last value of that row for all of successive values. If one value is 1.2 and the next for example 0.8, the values of the array should not be changed.

Here is my code:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,9,5,13,14,17,19,23,19,34,46,12,13,45,46,67,78,79]

b = Array.new
c = Array.new

a.each_cons(18) { |c| b.push(c[17]/c[0] }
```

Do you have an idea how to implement the condition?

Comment: Do you always have a fixed number of elements in the array?

Comment: Post intermediate and final result as well.

Comment: no, the number of elements changes

Comment: the intermediate result is the new array b. the final result is what I am looking for :)

Comment: "if two or more successive values are bigger than 1.2" Probably your whole array (which is a list of successive values) will meet this condition. Do you maybe want the smallest possible subset every time?

Comment: So please provide example in- and output for your problem.

Comment: the input is a time series with about 2000 values in array a. then I want to create a new array b, containing the values of the divisions described above  (a[17]/a[0] for the first element, a[18]/a[1] for the second element...). then I want to screen array b, and write the new values in the array c. if two or more successive values in b are >= 1.2, I want to write the division of the last and the first value of that row in the array c. for example if b=[1,2,3,1], the array c would be c= [1,1.5,1.5,1]. hope you understand what I want to do?

Comment: With the comments, there seems to have been enough information to answer this, but the question really should be edited so that it contain all of the information needed, without the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it, although I selectively interpreted some things from your question.  Specifically, in "of that row for all of successive values," does "row" refer to the sliding block from each_cons?  Ditto for "all of successive values."

```
catch (:done) do
  for i in 2..b.length do
    b.each_cons(i) do |d| 
      for j in 2..d.length do 
        d.each_cons(j) do |g|
          if g.all? { |g| g > 1.2 }
            c = b.map { |f| f + (d[0].to_f/d[i-1].to_f) }
            break
          end
          if !c.empty? then throw :done end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

puts c
```